# Derivative under summation and integral together

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

While solving some problem, I have the following question
\begin{align*}
g_{N}(\alpha)=\sum_{\vert k \vert\ge N+1}^{+\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\mathrm{i}x^2\cot\alpha}e^{\mathrm{i}k x}~\mathrm{d}x,
\end{align*}
where $N\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $0<\alpha<\pi/2$.
Can I differentiate term by term
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}g_{N}(\alpha)=\sum_{\vert k \vert\ge N+1}^{+\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\left(e^{\mathrm{i}x^2\cot\alpha}\right)e^{\mathrm{i}k x}~\mathrm{d}x?
\end{align*}
I am confused as series has terms which are integrals. If yes then please metion conditions. If not, then why not?

Comment: How did the limits of the sum change?

Comment: Sorry it was a  mistake in writing. I have made correction.

Comment: What are you summing though? Nothing in your equation is indexed by $k$.

Comment: Also, what is known about $f $?

Comment: Pulling in the derivative takes place in two steps: First you have to justify the interchange of $d/d\alpha$ with the summation, then the interchange with each of the integrals.

Comment: The question has significantly changed in content, I think this is asking a separate question.